# Problem with "gnome-terminal" on Gnome 3.12.2

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I have Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04 (Gnome 3.12.2).

When I try to run `gnome-terminal` by following command :

```
$ gnome-terminal
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal: /org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: 
Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: 
Process /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server exited with status 8
```

Comment: Experiencing the same error message on Ubuntu 19.04 / GNOME Terminal 3.34.2, I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128108/112190) worked.

Comment: If I open gnome-terminal from within a gnome-session, it works fine.  If I open it outside of gnome-session, such as when using my favorite window manager, fvwm, I have to use BarryPye's solution shown below.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to add `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to `/etc/default/locale` and reboot your system. (Solution from [this Arch Linux forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180103).)

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: Worked for me! It looks like I had LANG=en_US.UTF-8 in my file, but it was commented out. Uncommented it and rebooted, then gnome-terminal started right up.

Comment: 4y since this answer. and the user feedback when this is hit is still the same.

Answer (score 22):

Here is the list of commands which helps me:

```bsh
sudo apt install dconf-cli

# Reinstalling terminal
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal

# Reconfiguring locale
sudo locale-gen --purge
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

reboot
```

As you can see I just reconfigured the `locale` and reinstall `gnome-terminal`

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: helped in Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04

Comment: still works on 20.04 on EC2 :)

Comment: I incurred this problem after setting the default group to something other than my userid. The commands above fixed the problem for me selecting en_US.UTF-8 as my default locale when prompted. Note: if you elect to install all locales be prepared to wait a while (this isn't necessary, just install what you plan to use).

Comment: I tried all these options to no avail, as well as setting the language to English (US) in gnome-settings. What finally worked was changing the settings for dates under : Manage Installed Languages > Regional Formats > Display numbers, dates and currencies in the usual format for: English (US)

Answer (score 13):

This is a winner for me:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-launch /usr/bin/gnome-terminal &
```

as learned [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1828182#p1828182)

Comment: In my case, I was trying to run gnome-terminal from inside a shell created by Node.js... There was nothing wrong with my locale file and this solution executing it with dbus-launch was the one that really solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: I put the following in ~/.bashrc: alias gterm='/usr/bin/dbus-launch /usr/bin/gnome-terminal'

Answer (score 6):

This might be an issue with your locales. Either add `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to `/etc/locale.conf` and reboot or delete that file altogether (`sudo rm /etc/locale.conf && sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`) and reboot.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem when I created a new Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Desktop. The fix was to edit the `/etc/default/locale` file by adding the following line to the end of the file:

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Then reboot and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

Execute sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales in an alternative terminal emulator and select en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 , choose it as the default locale. gnome-terminal should work.

Answer (score 2):

I had to combine answers from @TomH and @BarryPye.  To get a gnome-terminal window:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/dbus-launch gnome-terminal
```

In my case, the issue was occuring in a VNC session.  I fixed it in my `~/.vnc/xstartup` by changing the window manager invocation to:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/dbus-launch /bin/gnome-session
```

Then gnome-terminal starts directly from command or the gnome graphical launcher, without the need to extra dbus-launch commands.

Answer (score 2):

I was at work today and desperate to get things moving. I found this

```
dbus-launch gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 1):

Another cause of the problem is that new preferences have been activated at the start of the session, check "Applications at startup" Preferences

Answer (score 1):

If anyone hits this error using waypipe, the [answer above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235679/844422) by [BarryPye](https://askubuntu.com/users/1005393/barrypye) shows the way.

e.g. `waypipe --compress lz4 ssh user@host "/usr/bin/dbus-launch /usr/bin/gnome-terminal &"`

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works for you, it could be that `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable is not set.

See if it's set with `echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.

If it's empty, set it with `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus`. You could also put this in your `~/.bashrc`.

Resourcese: [Dconf, can read value but not write it (given address is empty)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478536/dconf-can-read-value-but-not-write-it-given-address-is-empty)