# Unable to open gnome-terminal on 18.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I think it happened after running `apt upgrade` that my `gnome-terminal` won't open anymore. I've tried a few of the suggestions from other questions which said that re-generating the locales might fix it.

I've installed `xterm` and after a delay of about 40 seconds this is the output:

```
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

This gets printed in the syslog couple of times:

```
Aug 26 11:26:16 sirius at-spi-bus-launcher[1456]: dbus-daemon[1465]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.1005' (uid=1000 pid=9634 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real " label="unconfined")
Aug 26 11:26:16 sirius at-spi2-registr[9636]: Could not open X display
Aug 26 11:26:16 sirius at-spi-bus-launcher[1456]: dbus-daemon[1465]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Aug 26 11:26:16 sirius at-spi-bus-launcher[1456]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Aug 26 11:26:16 sirius at-spi2-registr[9636]: AT-SPI: Cannot open default display
```

Since there's an error regarding the default display, I also tried running `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal`, though with the same result. `sudo gnome-terminal` does open the terminal correctly. It also worked once when I ran `dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd --all` ([from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108808/gnome-terminal-fails-to-start-timed-out)) but after a reboot I get the following message:

```
# Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

Also tried the first five answers from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613582/terminal-wont-launch-after-upgrading).

**Update:** Here are the files that didn't belong to my user.

```
~$ find $HOME -not -user $USER
/home/dominic/.dbus/session-bus/35e9e36cbe34423e8c8274630326355c-0
find: ‘/home/dominic/.gvfs’: Permission denied
/home/dominic/.gvfs
find: ‘/home/dominic/.cache/doc’: Permission denied
/home/dominic/.cache/doc
/home/dominic/.cache/dconf/user
```

Changed the owner to my user and rebooted. Didn't have a `.dconf` but a `.gconf`. Rebooted again, but the terminal still doesn't open.

I also noticed when i run `sudo gnome-terminal` in `xterm` and then `su dominic` in `gnome-terminal` everything starts working. I can even close all `gnome-terminals` and open them again. After a reboot everything's back to being broken.

Comment: Can you create a test user? So we know if the error is general (system) or in your $HOME.

Comment: @nobody Created a test user and signed in with the default settings (Unity). Terminal opens just fine. I'm using Cinnamon

Comment: @nobody when I logout from `dominic`, log in and out of `testuser` and in as `dominic` again. The gnome-terminal works again. Just tried after a fresh reboot

Comment: It would be better to choose one Desktop an remove the other. Unity and cinnamon are botth GTK desktop and can affect each other.

Comment: @nobody seems like it's related to my user. `dominic` can't open the terminal in Unity and Cinnamon, `testuser` can open it in both environments

Comment: Never, ever use sudo for graphically programs like gnome-terminal. this way you will break the ownership from data's in your $HOME Use `sudo -H programname` or `pkexec programname`. fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Search, with 
`find $HOME -not -user $USER`  if some files are not belong to your user. Give them back to your user with

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/file
```

Log out and login again.

The next step will revert your attitude from your desktop-session.

```
mv $HOME/.dconf $HOME/.dconf.bak
```

and the same for

```
mv $HOME/.gconf $HOME/.gconf.bak
```

logout and login again.

Comment: I've added some updates to the questions. Thanks a lot for your help btw :)

Comment: There are no files in my `$HOME` not belonging to my user anymore. `.gconf` directory is also renamed. Still doesn't open

Comment: Sorry, here is very hot. I cleaned my answer for chown command. but if all files belong to your user, I have no Idea what is going wrong.