# Ubuntu 22.4 terminal not opening

Tags: command-line

The terminal won't open with neither pressing the program icon nor by CTRL+ALT+T.

I've tried

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3-minimal
```

using the terminal of VS code, but no luck.

BTW - I'm running via VirtualBox 7.0, on a Windows 11 host.

**EDIT (solved)**

After help from Jos (see comments), I added a line to the file `/dev/default/locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and rebooted.

Comment: What happens when you use the VS code terminal and enter `gnome-terminal`? At least you should see an error message.

Comment: # Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/608330/problem-with-gnome-terminal-on-gnome-3-12-2

Comment: @Jos - thanks. I added "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" at the end of the file /etc/default/locale and rebooted

Comment: Okay. I'll vote to close this question as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: Voted to close as dup of [Problem with "gnome-terminal" on Gnome 3.12.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608330/problem-with-gnome-terminal-on-gnome-3-12-2)